# How to create this View in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a view that returns information about articles whose condition on individual warehouses fell below 20% compared to the previous day. 
My table structure is as follows:

[image]

I have no idea how to create such a view. 
Any help or suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `LAG` window function for previous day

Comment: To me, it's not clear that you have any history in this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague.  For instance, what if data for a day is missing?  You also mention "warehouses", but there is no such field in the data. Similarly, "condition" is a bit hard to follow.  That said, let me assume that you mean "previous day *in the data* for individual articles and you are interested in quantities that fall by 20%".

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(t.quantity) over (partition by articlename order by dateadd) as prev_quantity
      from t
     )  t
where t.quantity < t.prev_quantity * (1 - 0.2);
```

Comment: @k_dadun . . . . `t` is for your table name.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gordon Linoff